# How to save event jquery with localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have error with localStorage

> Uncaught TypeError:localStorage.toggleSidebarCheck is not a function

I want to save the event when it clicked and although reload the page, the settings I click remain unchanged.

This my javascript:

```js
$('.sidebar-toggle').click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem(toggleSidebarCheck).click();
});
```

Comment: what is `toggleSidebarCheck` suppost to be?

Comment: localStorage requires a key. You can set it like this: `localStorage.setItem(key, value)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Answer (score -3):

```
$('.sidebar-toggle').click(function() {
    //assign your onclick result to one variable,like
    var toggleItem = "Hiiiii";

    //assign that variable to localStorage.setItem, like this
    localStorage.setItem('item', toggleItem);
});
```

// refresh page and see the alert message as Hiiiii

```
 alert(localStorage.getItem('item'));
```

Comment: It's just a variable, i have given example code with comments. and i worked with these type of localStorage in many projects

Comment: You can't set a localStorage the way you do it.

Comment: i have edited code, check once. we can set the localStogare like that

Comment: first test once and then let me know. i can challenge that we can store in localStorage like my code

Comment: @rajpeer alert should be getItem, not setItem.

Comment: @Shiladitya His code was correct. He is using object like syntax to assign value to `setItem`, your edit won't work.